# Careers suggests a job filter that is useless in certain locales

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, internationalization

I have noticed, although right now I don't seem to be able to find the page that shows this by default, that the Jobs page suggests a possible job search filter for "10+ vacation days". This also appears under the 'Perks' filter when filtering all jobs.

This is useless in the UK (where I am) and also most of the EU, as the legal minimum number of days vacation for a salaried position is 20 days. It would also not be considered a 'perk' in these countries as it is a legally mandated entitlement.

Better site localisation ought to display filtering options for vacation that are useful to people in regions with different cultural expectations of paid leave to that of the United States.

*Edit June, 2020:*

This feature has resurfaced in a different format:

[image: StackOverflow Jobs Perks filter]

For a technology role in the UK, over 25 days would be worthwhile as a filter, for people interested in such a thing.

Comment: **10 days leave counts as a perk?** *I pity the fool*

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your feedback! We've been running an experiment on those filters (that we named "Collections") to measure how interesting they are to our users.

We're not going to be graduating it as it is... and if the one about vacation days makes it, I agree with you that it needs to better account for different local expectations.